# HTTP Tools for analysis and capture of requests/response

Tags: http, fiddler, httpwatch

I am looking for tools that can be used for debugging web applications.I have narrowed my search to the following tools:

1. HTTPwatch.
2. Fiddler.
3. ieHTTPheader
4. liveHTTPheader.

It would be great if some of you having experience with these tools could discuss their pros and cons (features that you like or you think are missing in some of the tools but present in others).I am majorly confused between HTTPWatch and Fiddler, I would prefer Fiddler (being free) if it could fullfill all or most of HTTPWatch's features (however I am ready to pay for HTTPWatch if it's worth it).

P.S. - I know HTTPWatch and Fiddler are far more powerful than the other two tools (let me know if you disagree).
I am sure most of you would want more details as to what I would exactly like to do with these tools however I would like if you could compare these tools taking a broader perspective in mind comparing them as tools in general.

Comment: I like WireShark too, though it's not necessarily specialized like these other tools

Answer (score 8):

** Disclaimer: Posted by Simtec Limited **

Here's a list of the main advantages of HttpWatch (our product) and Fiddler. Of course we're biased, but we've tried to be objective:

**HttpWatch Advantages**

- Shows requests that were read from
  the browser cache without going onto network
- Shows page level events, e.g. Render Start, DOM Load, etc
- Handles SSL  traffic without certificate warnings or requiring changes to trusted root CAs
- Reduces 'observer effect' by not requiring HTTP proxy at network level
- Groups requests by page

**Fiddler Advantages**

- Works with almost any HTTP client not just Firefox and IE
- Can intercept traffic from clients on non-Windows platforms, e.g. mobile devices
- Requests can be intercepted and modified on the fly, e.g. change cookie value
- Supports plugins to add extra functionality

Comment: I like that you have accepted your biasses*** honest!

If you can specify some of the disadvantages that will be helpful as well. :)

Comment: I assume a feature in one list is thus a disadvantage in the other. A very half-glass-full type of post.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark works at the network layer and of course gives you more information that the other tools you have mentioned here, however, if you want to debug web applications by breaking on requests/responses, modifying them and replaying - Fiddler is the tool for you!

Fiddler cannot however show TCP level information however and in such cases you will need Network Monitor or Wireshark.

If you specify what exactly you want to do with the 'debugger', one can suggest what's more appropriate for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Fidler is good and simple to use. Wireshark is also worth considering since it gives a lot of extra information

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which allows you to analyze many protocols including TCP/IP.

A lab exercise from a University lecture on using Wireshark to analyze HTTP can be found here: [Wireshark Lab: HTTP](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~netlab/resources/booklet/Wireshark_HTTP.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com)

It works with all browsers and custom software and doesn't change proxy settings.

Comment: Firefox blocks this site as 'adware'